# Shiny.Semantic sidebar layout not conforming to expected behavior in R

Tags: r, shiny, semantic-ui

The [Shiny.semantic repo](https://appsilon.github.io/shiny.semantic/articles/intro.html) identifies the following example code below.
In the UI Presentation this shows as having a sidebar and then one panel with two cards side by side.  However, when running this locally in a Golem project, I am seeing everything stacked vertically and the sidebar does not exhibit the sidebar behavior.

Additionally, I moved this code into its own non-project R file and ran it with the same behavior, both in the preview window of RStudio and of Chrome.

Has anyone seen this behavior, any thoughts on a fix?  I will be testing with R 4.X a bit later but hoping this is not a version issue.

```
ui <- semanticPage(


title = "My first page",
  h1("My page"),
  sidebar_layout(
    sidebar_panel(
      dropdown_input("mtcars_dropdown", c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"), value = "mpg"),
      textOutput("dropdown")
    ),
    main_panel(
      segment(
         cards(
           class = "two",
           card(class = "red",
             div(class = "content",
                 div(class = "header", "Main title card 1"),
                 div(class = "meta", "Sub title card 1"),
                 div(class = "description", "More detail description card 1")
             )
           ),
           card(class = "blue",
             div(class = "content",
                 div(class = "header", "Main title card 2"),
                 div(class = "meta", "Sub title card 2"),
                 div(class = "description", "More detail description card 2")
             )
           )
         )
      )
      )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dropdown <- renderText(input$mtcars_dropdown)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          3
minor          6.3
year           2020
month          02
day            29
svn rev        77875
language       R
version.string R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
nickname       Holding the Windsock

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
The following code explicitly should set the grid system to replicate what should be native.  When running in R version 4.0.3 this also still displays everything vertically.

```
ui <- semanticPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    
    grid(
        grid_template = grid_template(
            default = list(
                areas = rbind(
                    c("title", "title"),
                    c("sidebar", "cardarea"),
                    c("sidebar", "cardarea")
                ),
                cols_width = c("25%", "75%"),
                rows_height = c("40px", "100px", "auto")
            )
        ),
    
    
    
    title = "My first page",
    h1("My page"),
    sidebar = sidebar_layout(
        sidebar_panel(
            dropdown_input("mtcars_dropdown", c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"), value = "mpg"),
            textOutput("dropdown")
        ),
        main_panel()
    ),
        cardarea = 
            segment(
                cards(
                    class = "two",
                    card(class = "red",
                         div(class = "content",
                             div(class = "header", "Main title card 1"),
                             div(class = "meta", "Sub title card 1"),
                             div(class = "description", "More detail description card 1")
                         )
                    ),
                    card(class = "blue",
                         div(class = "content",
                             div(class = "header", "Main title card 2"),
                             div(class = "meta", "Sub title card 2"),
                             div(class = "description", "More detail description card 2")
                         )
                    )
                )
            )
        
    )
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$dropdown <- renderText(input$mtcars_dropdown)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also attempted to compare an app that uses Shiny.Semantic from the 2020 competition.  This is from the FIFA example on the Appsilon.ai site
[image]

This is from the same code running locally.  The color is different and the layout is incorrect.
[image]

Comment: I see all the UI components side by side, same as it is shown in their repo. I am on R 4.0.3 though but I highly doubt this is an R version issue.

Comment: I also doubt it is a version issue.  Loaded it up at home on my MAC in R 4.0.3 and am seeing it vertical as well.   Very perplexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formatting issue appears to be related to the current git release of shiny.semantic. Version 0.4.2

Uninstalling the release version and installing the development version corrects the issue and shiny.semantic correctly formats as expected.

remotes::install_github("Appsilon/shiny.semantic@develop")